# logging exception in .net core worker process

Tags: c#, serilog

i have below code in .net core worker process.

```
public void GenerateException()
{
    try
    {
        int i = 10;
        int j = 0;
        int k = i / j;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Exception at GenerateException", ex);
    }
}
```

I am using https://serilog.net/ as logging framework. The issue is this does not log exception. it only logs below line but not actual exception

```
2021-11-12 11:52:34.359 +05:30 [ERR] Exception at GenerateException
```

What am i doing wrong?

With some googling found that i had to swap the parameters in `_logger.LogError` like `_logger.LogError(ex,"Exception at GenerateException")`;

Comment: Possible duplicate of question (w/o answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67211647/logging-exceptions-with-serilog

Comment: no answers there as well

Comment: TBH: Serilog in its source code use logging as `_logger.Error(...)` . Even on their webpage they have `log.Information(...)`. What is that `LogError` message and where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

Check [official site](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events). This page mentioned that you should write like this:

```
_logger.LogError("Exception at GenerateException {Exception}", ex);
```

ex will be formatted into the position of {Exception}.